# Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException when updating Azure.Identity from version 1.7

Tags: azure-functions, azure-identity

I'm trying to update my Azure function project to use a newer version of Azure.Identity than 1.7. I'm using the .net6 and v4 functions. I've tried with 1.8, 1.9, and 1.10 versions of Azure. Identity but I get the error below. Version 1.7 works fine but it has vulnerabilities so I need to update it.

[image]

Comment: It fails when my trigger functions starts.

public async Task ServiceBusTriggerAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage serviceBusMessage)

Comment: Please do not present text rendered as a pixel raster.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `Azure.Identity` with version `1.10` in .NET 6.0.
- To resolve your issue, try sign out and sign in to your account in visual studio.
- Go to `Tools => Options =>Azure Service Authentication => Account Selection`  sign in to your account.

[image]
I have tried using `Azure.Identity` package version `1.10` in my Http triggered Azure function and it worked as expected.

**Function.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
 {
     string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("<keyvault_name>");
     var kvUri = "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/";

     var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
     var secretName = "kvsecret";
     var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

     string keyVaultValue = secret.Value.Value;
     log.LogInformation("The Secret Name: " + secretName + " and the secret value: "+ keyVaultValue);
     return new OkObjectResult("The secret value: "+keyVaultValue);
 }
```

**.csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't help

Comment: Can you create a new function app and try the steps I have given?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a false error. The function works as expected even though the exception is thrown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).